# Notify multiple threads periodically

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask, periodic-task

I'm working on a project that uses primitive Java concurrent structures such as wait(), notify(), notifyAll(), Thread.run(), synhronized etc. 
On my project, there are multiple threads (a extension of Thread class) who will get an object from a queue periodically. Thus, I use a Timer class which has an inner TimerTask class.

My problem is that, I could not get how to make other threads wake up periodically. My main class is not these threads or timer classes. Thus I call their run from another class. I could not figure out how to make these threads wait and notify for one time per 100 miliseconds. My timer class is:

```
public class Controller extends Timer{

    int counter;
    TimerTask task;
    final Controller c = this;

    public class PeriodicTime extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(counter > 0) {
                //do some stuff to wake up threads

            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

    Controller () {
        super ();
        this.task = new PeriodicTime();
        counter = 0;
        this.schedule(task, 300, 100);
    } 
}
```

And my thread class is:

```
public class Element extends Thread {


    public void run() {

        // do something to get an object from another class (a queue)
    }
}
```

Now, i'm really confused how to make periodic releasing to the thread class. I even could not get whether to use wait()/notify() or not.

As I told before, i'll create multiple Element class. They will work synchronized. Then, what should I do?

Comment: I assume this is homework, as you really would not do it this way if you had a choice.  An ExecutorService does what you want much simpler.

Comment: To perform a wait/notify, you need access to a common object where one waits while the other notifies.  You mention a `queue` how is this used?

Comment: Yes this is a homework, thus i cannot choose the way of doing it. 
My queue has a "put" and "get" method whose works synchronized. I put "wait" and "notify" in those methods depending on the object count.

Comment: In that case, if they are implemented correctly, you don't need ntoify/wait or at least those methods should do this.

Comment: But how should i make the Element objects' getting process periodically?

Comment: Normally you would get the element as soon as it is added.  Do you want to wake the thread even if there is nothing to do?

Comment: Yes, and in some cases maybe element won't take anything. But they will be warned periodically and report their situation (these are of course details)

Comment: Also when they get the object in queue, another class's thread object (i didn't mention this) adds a new object to this queue. But, i don't want the new object's being taken by the same thread in the same period. I hope i'm clear.

Comment: Re, "... Thus i call their run from another class.":  If you're calling `t.run()` where `t instanceof Thread`, then you probably are making a big mistake.  A `Thread` instance is not a thread; it's only a handle that you use to _manage_ a thread.  The thread does not even exist until your code calls `t.start()`.  The `start()` method is provided by the library for you to call when you want to start a new thread.  The `run()` method is provided by _you_ for the _library_ to call _in_ the new thread.

Comment: No, i used start(). Therefore there's no problem of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of Objects that will represent mutexes, Each Element thread will get one mutex from the list, while the timer task gets the list.

TimerTask calls notify() on every mutex object when the time period expires. This wakes up the Element threads.

Element threads process data from queue and when they are done they each call wait() on their mutex object.

Now you need thread safety built into the queue since there are multiple consumers, but not the blocking logic since it is handled by the TimerTask.

Also, if I understood you correctly, you want Elements put something back to queue as they process the data. For that you can use an auxilary queue that you can drain into the first one after elements are done or you can just swap them (This is done by TimerTask and requires an atomic counter that will get incremented when Element wakes up and decremented when it goes to sleep). Alternatively, you can use a "stop" value that you can put into queue just before you wake up Elements, and make them work until they reach it. For N element threads you would need to put N stop values so all of them get the message.

How to use mutexes:

```
List<Object> mutexList;
//initialize the list with plain Objects. You just need them to be separate instances.
....
//When creating Element threads add one object from the list to each Element.
....
//in Element code
public class Element extends Thread {
   //This is one element from the list 
   private Object mutex;


    public void run() {
       // do something to get an object from another class (a queue)
       //....
       synchronized(mutex){ 
          mutex.wait();
       }
    }
}
// in timerTask code
 public class PeriodicTime extends TimerTask {

    List<Object> mutexList;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(counter > 0) {
            //do some stuff to wake up threads
           for(Object mutex:mutexList){
                mutex.notify();
           }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, elements won't put the data back. There's an "owner" class who puts new data to the queue whenever someone takes one. If i'm not wrong, putting process works correcytly and it does not need periodic thing. 

But still i'm not sure how to use mutex objects. Can't you give simple code example for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added a simple case for using mutexes. Keep in mind though, that depending on your needs you may to improve upon this because there are cases when this setup can produce unwanted behaviour, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But still it works for only one time, i don't know why. Anyway, thanks again. Let me solve it in some way.

Comment: And i handled it. All i need was one while(true) loop on your solution. It's ok now.